# downloading and playing a mp3 asynchronously

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have to play a file which we get from a server.I have to download the file asynchronously and save it in documents directory.Here is what i tried:

```
 NSData * _objectData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
     NSError *error;
        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:_objectData error:&error];
        audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 1;

        if (audioPlayer == nil)
            NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
        else
            [audioPlayer play];
```

Comment: what is the issue or problem???

Comment: how do i do it asynchronously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Mattgallagher's [AudioStreamer](https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer/blob/master/Classes/AudioStreamer.h) for `streaming mp3`.

For `downloading` follow [these](https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer/issues/41) `link`.

@Enjoy.

Comment: AudioStreamer simply streams the file. You may as well init an AVPlayerItem with a URL and use AVPlayer to play the item. I believe the OP wanted to download the file and save it to the Documents folder

Comment: @MDB983 read my anwser again to know how it can be download as well